# Rails Find with Active Resource Ignoring Parameters

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, activeresource

I have two Rails apps, one client using ActiveResource and one service.  I am testing the following command via the console:

```
User.find(:all, :params => {:email_address => "myemail@domain.com"})
```

I get back all the records in my user table and not just the one specified in my email parameter.

When I go look at the log for my service app it shows as follows

```
Started GET "/users.json?email_address=myemail%40domain.com" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-12-29 11:29:06 -0600
   (0.4ms)  SHOW search_path
  Processing by UsersController#index as JSON
  Parameters: {"email_address"=>"myemail@domain.com"}
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" 
Completed 200 OK in 40ms (Views: 35.7ms | ActiveRecord: 3.3ms)
```

My parameter was not included in the SQL statement.

Any insight?

Comment: please post your service app users_controller index method

Comment: try using :conditions instead of :params

Comment: Here is my index      

at users = User.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @users }
    end


Using conditions doesnt pass throught the params and produces this

Started GET "/users.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-12-29 12:08:41 -0600
  Processing by UsersController#index as JSON
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" 
Completed 200 OK in 12ms (Views: 7.0ms | ActiveRecord: 4.1ms)

Comment: The User controller and model on both the client and service were generated from a scaffold and are so far unchanged except for changing the model on the client side to use Active Resource and set the self.site url.

Comment: @user1084769, are you sure you're talking about ActiveResource and not ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment on the original question, your controller still looks like this:

```
class UsersController < ActionController::Base 
 def index
   @users = User.all
   respond_to do |format|
     format.json { render json: @users }
   end
 end
   #other methods down here
end
```

But in order to get your index view to render just the ones that match the email, you need to update the index method to:

```
class UsersController < ActionController::Base 
 def index
   @users = User.find_all_by_email_address(email_address)
   respond_to do |format|
     format.json { render json: @users }
   end
 end
   #other methods down here
end
```

Comment: thanks jstim.  i found the distinction between params and conditions with relation to activeresource and activerecord to be the same as well.  my goal is to login a user from the activeresource client to the activerecord service app.  when the two parameters are validated the user data is sent back to the client so i can set a session.  

in my original question i was first trying to send an email address and get back a user but have still been unsuccessful.  when i query data like this out of the normal by id, do i need special routes or something in the controllers to handle this?

Comment: I don't think you need anything special. These are all available as part of AR or AS. As someone mentioned above, though, there may be something in your controller that is overriding this search. Can you post your controller?

Comment: To clarify as well, which app holds the User table? Is it the one using AR or AS? Are you caching users on both sides or could you be getting your db calls mixed up?

Comment: ActiveRecord holds the user table.

Comment: so all this talk about ActiveResource isn't relevant to the question of the search syntax. I'll update my answer to show the proper AR calls, but it would still be helpful to see your controller to confirm there isn't something overwriting your search.

Comment: The User controller and model on both the client and service were generated from a scaffold and are so far unchanged except for changing the model on the client side to use Active Resource and set the self.site url.

Comment: This is a long shot but is there any way your app cached the original request and is just hitting the cache instead of polling the db? Should show up in your development log if so.

Comment: possible.  I was running these queries in terminal on the mac

Comment: I think you are onto something in your code example, but what does the controller look like on the activeresource side?

Comment: @user1084769 try this on the service app side `@users = User.where params`. This way all queries would be supported and not just by_email_address.

Answer (score 0):

Conditions are passed to ActiveRecord `find` method via `:conditions` option and not `:params`. So your `find` call should be like that:

```
User.find(:all, :conditions => { :email_address => "myemail@domain.com" })
```

or in more Rails 3 style:

```
User.where(:email_address => "myemail@domain.com").all
```

You can find full list of available parameters for `find` method in [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/find).